# Multiple Resource Dictionaries

Tags: silverlight, resourcedictionary

Hey all, quick question about Silverlight Resource Dictionaries.

So in resource dictionary number 1, I have a data template. That data template contains a hyperlink button. My hyperlink button style is defined in resource dictionary number 2.

Could someone explain how I have to set up my dictionary references and merges and all that stuff so that using the data template will actually apply the correct style to the hyperlink button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was a stupid fix...

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="WidgetStyles.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```